# Dependency missing: rust nightly - Rust not installed

Tags: rust, smartcontracts, multiversx, erdpy

I try to configure Ubuntu VM for MultiversX developers. I follow the instructions on the [site](https://docs.multiversx.com/), but when I try to compile a smart contract I get the bellow issue:

> Rust is not installed on your machine. Run `mxpy deps install rust --overwrite` and try again.
> **CRITICAL** cli: Dependency missing: rust nightly-2023-12-11
> Dependency missing: rust nightly-2023-12-12

But Rust is installed.

The following command:

```
rustup show
```

displays:

```
installed targets for active toolchain
---------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-2023-12-11-x86_64-unknwon-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.76.0-nightly (d86d65bbc 2023-12-10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `pkg-config` with `libssl-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config libssl-dev
```

Then install rust from `mxpy` CLI:

```
mxpy deps install rust —overwrite
```

After these, the smart contract should compile.

Other possible useful details can be found under [SDK and Tools > Troubleshooting > Fix Rust installation](https://docs.multiversx.com/sdk-and-tools/troubleshooting/rust-setup#handle-missing-dependencies-of-sc-meta).

Answer (score -1):

I'm having issues with downloading wasm-opt through cargo it gets held up in processes at 57 of 63, but I am not understanding why, I am following along with this install on mvx, this has gotten me farther than before so that is a huge plus, great write up, side note do I need wasm-opt? or can i still build contacts without it? Any follow up information would be appreciated, thanks in Advance

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).